# Rails 4 - Compare data from MySQL and SQLite

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to compare data on my external data and saved data on local Rails db and if something change on external db, also change it on local.

I'm so far here:

**MY MODEL**

```
def self.updatedata
   user = Account.updatedata
   stats = Status.all

   user.each do |u|
      id = u.accountId
      stats = u.accountStatus

      if stats.user_id != id && stats.user_status != u.stats
          p "It's Changed"
      end
   end
end
```

**Account.update (external)** data I'm getting: `Account.select('accountId', 'accountStatus')` that saving `user_id = accountId, user_status = accountStatus`

Then im printing **Status.all (local)** there is a `id, user_id, user_status, timestamps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is your use case? If your trying just keep the Status model up to date with the Account model, I would do this.

Utilize the gem octopus to handle connecting to both an external and local data sources. You can even specify 1 source per model in your model's code (or shard at runtime)
https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

Then on your Account model you can set up an after_commit callback that can go ahead and set the data on your Status model. You could even have it kick off ActiveJobs to do this if you expect it to receive a large volume of changes quickly.